# How to perform string split based on space for Platform::String^

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

In C++/CX Windows App Store, how do we perform string split based on space, for `Platform::String^`? I just can't find the Split function.

Comment: I think you mean C++/CX, not C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isn't a split method because Microsoft has said (for now) that they don't intend to add one.  In the documentation for the [Platform::String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699879.aspx) class they state:

> Text in the Windows Runtime is represented in C++/CX by the
>   Platform::String Class. Use the Platform::String Class when you pass
>   strings back and forth to methods in Windows Runtime classes, or when
>   you are interacting with other Windows Runtime components across the
>   application binary interface (ABI) boundary. The Platform::String
>   Class provides methods for several common string operations, but it's
>   not designed to be a full-featured string class. In your C++ module,
>   use standard C++ string types such as wstring for any significant text
>   processing, and then convert the final result to Platform::String^
>   before you pass it to or from a public interface. It's easy and
>   efficient to convert between wstring or wchar_t* and Platform::String.
>   (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699879.aspx)

Given what's above your best bet is to work with strings from std and work with one of the many different implementations of split.  There are some great recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c).

I hope this helps.